# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been reading the whole day other Stackoverflow questions and other post looking for the error. But nothing worked for me. 
I have read also that Doctrine have some difficulties in terms of managing more than one many-to-one relationships. So I believe that mixing two one-to-many and one many-to-many assosiation in the same Entity is just exploding when I try to update the Data Base.

I am working with Symfony2, Doctrine2 and mySQL and the error appears when I use doctrine command for updating the DB.If I use generate:entities it doesn't cry. Problems started when I tried to add Project entity. Before, relations between Document, Translation and User were working fine.
here you are my related attributes in my entities:

Document:

```
 class DocumentDictionary
    {

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProjectDictionary", inversedBy="documents")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
         */
        private $project;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="documents")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $creator;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TranslationDictionary", inversedBy="documents")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="translations_in_documents") 
         */
        private $translations;

//...Constructor, getters, settesr and few more attributes
```

The Project class (1:N with Document):

```
class ProjectDictionary 
{
     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DocumentDictionary", mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $documents;
//Again more class stuff..
```

Translation (N:M):

```
    class TranslationDictionary
    {
     /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
         private $id;

         /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="DocumentDictionary", mappedBy="translations")
         */
        private $documents;
```

And finally User class(1:N):

```
    class User extends BaseUser
        {        
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;



         /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
         *
         */
        protected $language;
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DictionaryBundle\Entity\DocumentDictionary", mappedBy="creator")
     */
    protected $documents;
```

Any idea? Anybody knows how to mix theese relationships properly?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**I have finally give up. I just deleted my Project entity and created again. It is now working, so I suppose there was a mistake somewhere. 
Thanks everybody anyway! How can I close the question?

Comment: Your annotations in TranslationDictionary entitiy are very strange..

Comment: Thanks somehow some lines mixed when I copied them. I have edited the question. But they are fine in my code. thats not the problem.

Comment: Yes, it was. But I have more or less solve it.